# How to make other styles set as default when we changing class of element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created div and place it right margin of the page with `position:fixed`. I need to place the div to bottom margin when I call the JavaScript function. I tried to use `classList.add()` and `classList.remove()` to accomplish my task.

here is the CSS classes I created,

```
.example-right{
        position:fixed;
        top:50px;
        right:0px;
    }
.example-bottom{
        position:fixed;
        left:50px;
        bottom:0px;
    }
```

This is JavaScript code what I tried,

```
function test(){
  document.getElementById('target').classList.remove('example-right');
  document.getElementById('target').classList.add('example-bottom');
}
```

When I trigger the `test()` function it removes the `example-right` and replace it with `example-bottom`. But the div's top value is not going to change after the function is triggered. So, it is not place the div on bottom margin of the window. I can put`top:## px;` to `example-bottom`. But when page is resizing and

Is it possible to Solve this problem using CSS. I know I can use `document.getElementById('target').style.top = window.innerHeight- div_Height` to change the top value. but I like to know is there any way to do it using css or another method. (otherwise I have to use JavaScript all the times when I need to change the position)

**pure CSS and JavaScript only**

Comment: do you need to change position on screen size change ? 
or just move position on button or any specific element click ?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, working example? What you've shown so far should not cause any errors.

Comment: @AshokDevatwal :Actually It is for clickfunction. and It shuld fixed to screen bottom after I click.

Comment: then you can go with Mr. karthipan raj's answer . its good enough to your task .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You . have done right. Only thing is understanding a  bit of css more.

```css
.example-right{
        position:fixed;
        top:50px;
        right:0px;
    }
.example-bottom{
        position:fixed;
        top:inital
        left:50px;
        bottom:0px;
    }
```

Comment: **If** what the poster provided is everything, `top: initial` isn't needed, as `top: 50px` is no longer being applied to the element. Needless to say, their example isn't replicable.

Answer (score 0):

add this css

```
.example-right{
        position:fixed;
        top:50px;
        right:0px;
    }
.example-bottom{
        position:fixed;
        left:50px;
        bottom:0px;
        top:auto;
    }
```

```js
function test(){
  document.getElementById('target').classList.remove('example-right');
  document.getElementById('target').classList.add('example-bottom');
}
```

```css
.example-right{
        position:fixed;
        top:50px;
        right:0px;
    }
.example-bottom{
        position:fixed;
        left:50px;
        bottom:0px;
        top:auto;
    }
    #target{
      width:200px;
      height:200px;
      background:red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="target" class="example-right">

</div>
<br/>
<button onclick="test()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Note that setting `top: auto` isn't necessary for what the poster said. Their example can't be replicated, as they haven't provided the full details.